# string from fetch method to be rendered via express-handlebars (JS)

Tags: javascript, fetch, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I'm totally new to express-handlebars currently trying to render a list of strings using a helper function. The strings are stemming from a filtered json response object using the fetch API and the node-fetch module. 
I can console.log the json results just fine, however I am unbable to render those sentences to my page.

here's my code:

helper function

```
module.exports = zodiac => {
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const URL = `https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/?sign=${zodiac}&day=today`;
    fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json.description);
            return json.description;
        });
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="board" id="board--dobs">
        <h2>DOB</h2>
        <ul>
            {{#each bdays}}
            <li>{{this.dob}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="board" id="board--starsigns">
        <h2>Star sign</h2>
        <ul>
            {{#each bdays}}
            <li>{{toZodiac this.dob}}</li>
            {{/each}}

     <section class="board" id="board--horoscopes">
        <h2>Horoscope</h2>
        <ul>
            {{#each bdays}}
            <li>{{horoscope (toZodiac this.dob)}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
     </section>
```

My page has 3 sections where the first two are running fine:

1. Showing a date of birth (DOB) stemming from a database
2. converting the date into a star sign string (zodiac) using a helper function called toZodiac
3. making an api call to fetch a daily horoscope and render it to the page 

   `{{horoscope (toZodiac this.dob)}}`

   logs out the json.response but I don't know why it doesn't get rendered to the page...

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZZ6f.png)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I believe your `horoscope` helper is fetching data asynchronously. This isn't going to work as a helper. You will need to find a way to render the template _after_ the async data has been fetched.